# Separar lo que viene con comas

Tags: php

Hola estoy utilizando laravel filemanger y a la hora de hacer multiple carga de fotos, me los separa los archivos por coma al hacer submit.

```
galeria[]: /storage/photos/1/Productos/bandeja1.png,/storage/photos/1/Productos/bandeja2.png
```

Mi pregunta es, una vez recibo esto en el controlador puedo hacer que cada foto sea idependiente?? para hacer un foreach y meter cada una por fila??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cuenta con la función [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), la cual separa una cadena según determinado caracter.

```php
$pizza  = "porción1,porción2,porción3,porción4,porción5,porción6";
$porciones = explode(",", $pizza);
echo $porciones[0]; // porción1
echo $porciones[1]; // porción2
```

Cabe mencionar que el inverso de esta función es [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php).

Comment: Brillante voy a probarlo a ver que tal! gracias @BaruchSpinoza

Comment: Me devuelve esto `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: Nada ok solucionado,  en el `input name="nombre[]"` tenia puesto `[ ]` gracias funciono a la perfección